# terraform condition inside list with null value

Tags: function, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

I'm trying to create an AWS ACM cert. I want the subject alternative list to vary depending on what environment we are deploying into, however terraform doesn't accept null values in a list. The below results in an error "Null values are not allowed for this attribute value"

This is what I'm attempting:

```
 resource "aws_acm_certificate" "acm" {
      domain_name               = var.env_name == "prod" ? "*.${var.base_domain}" : "*.${var.env_name}.${var.base_domain}"
      validation_method         = "DNS"
      subject_alternative_names = [var.env_name == "prod" ? var.base_domain : null, "*.${data.terraform_remote_state.dns.outputs.domain}"]
}
```

Other attempts I've tried:

```
subject_alternative_names = [compact(var.base_domain, "*.${data.terraform_remote_state.dns.outputs.domain}")]

subject_alternative_names = compact(["*.${data.terraform_remote_state.dns.outputs.domain}"], tolist(var.env_name == "prod" ? var.base_domain : null))

subject_alternative_names = [var.env_name == "prod" ? var.base_domain : [], "*.${data.terraform_remote_state.dns.outputs.domain}"]
```

but these all return errors.

I've tried various other methods on the sans list but can't get any of them to work. Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Comment: What about an empty list, i.e., `[]` instead of `null`?

Comment: ...is for sure the correct answer as long as the provider validates it as an input, and the API allows it or the provider assists when interfacing.

Comment: hi @MarkoE thanks but that returns the error "The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
│ expressions are string and tuple, respectively."

Comment: What is the code that caused that error? One of the attempts above or something else?

Comment: I tried your suggestion of: [var.env_name == "prod" ? var.base_domain : [ ], "*.${data.terraform_remote_state.dns.outputs.domain}"] and that is what returned the error. Added it to my question too

Comment: I got it to work. Posted my answer. Thanks @MarkoE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it  working with the below (first attempt):

```
compact(concat(tolist([var.env_name == "prod" ? var.base_domain : null]), ["*.${data.terraform_remote_state.dns.outputs.domain}"]))
```

then realised it could be simpler with (second attempt):

```
compact([var.env_name == "prod" ? var.base_domain : null, "*.${data.terraform_remote_state.dns.outputs.domain}"])
```

I was just getting the syntax wrong earlier